# Expr command returns false

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to use this command line

```
expr 916.1 '<' 1024
```

But I get a `false` response (return 1)

Comment: what would you expect to return? I've never seen this before but 961.1 seems to be smaller than 1024 at least comparing two float values...

Comment: The expected result of the command: `expr 916.1 '<' 1024` is `0`

Answer (score 12):

[`expr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/expr-invocation.html) does not support floating-point numbers:

> Operands are either integers or strings. Integers consist of one or
>   more decimal digits, with an optional leading ‘-’. expr converts
>   anything appearing in an operand position to an integer or a string
>   depending on the operation being applied to it.

[And](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Relations-for-expr.html#Relations-for-expr):

> expr first tries to convert both arguments to integers and do a
>   numeric comparison; if either conversion fails, it does a
>   lexicographic comparison using the character collating sequence
>   specified by the LC_COLLATE locale.

If you want to compare floats, use something like `bc` (which uses the "0 is false, 1 is true" convention):

```
expr1 < expr2
      The result is 1 if expr1 is strictly less than expr2.
```

So:

```
$ bc <<< '(916.1 < 1024)'
1
$ if [ "$(bc <<< '(916.1 < 1024)')" -eq 1 ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
yes
```

Comment: exp="$(bc <<< '($var1 < $var2)')"
echo ":$exp"
exp=`bc <<< '(${var1} < ${var2})'`
echo ":$exp"
i have this error

Comment: (standard_in) 1: illegal character: $

Comment: @khiatabdelhamid stop posting multiple comments. Also, variable expansion doesn't happen in single quotes. Use double quotes.

Comment: @khiatabdelhamid It looks like you may have a separate question about [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting). It seems muru [may already have answered it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956989/expr-command-returns-false#comment1527511_956994) but, if not, then you may want to [post a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).